# need to boot back into windows 8

Tags: boot, grub2, windows, restore

i don't know exactly what topic i should read, but i thought it would be better to just post this. i have an acer laptop, and i was locked out of the bios. i wanted to try something new and installed ubuntu. i found that i don't like it. i can't even install apps like i can on windows. you have to type in all these codes. i just want to go back to windows. i was doing all this stuff to try to get back to windows, and actually got into the bios. i don't know exactly what order to put in the bios to boot into my original os. i don't know how to use grub 2. i'm very unfamiliar with everything. i kinda know something about the terminal. by the way i chose install when i first booted into the usb that had the iso file on it. i know i should have tried try ubuntu instead. i need some very clear instructions on how to boot into my original os and use windows. sorry again if this is duplicates of other topics. i just don't know what to look for. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A **Temporary** solution I usually rely on is "[Super Grub2 Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/)"

1. Download the first "[Recommended download](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/2014/05/21/super-grub2-disk-2-00s2-downloads/)".
2. Burn the ISO on a CD (I think Brasero Disc Burner comes default with Ubuntu).
3. Boot the PC off it (Like you did with Ubuntu CD during the installation).
4. Choose "Everything", then choose your windows installation.

If this works, and the windows is OK, you can try to make that windows drive your default boot drive, but that's out of the scope of my **temporary** answer.

I'm assuming here that you didn't actually wipe out your windows installation during Ubuntu's, but rather choose to install it side by side on a separate drive (This you can easily check from Ubuntu using "Files" application to search for a drive (Under "Devices") that looks like your windows drive).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear Ubuntu didn't work out for you. Ubuntu is able to install apps, and it's actually easier once you get the hang of how it's different to Windows.

If you're determined to return to Windows though you'll want to repair your boot loader. To do this you'll need to install [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu).

After running "recommended repair" and rebooting you will be presented with a screen that allows you to select either Windows or Ubuntu to load.

Just a note, the method for installing boot-repair suggested in the link requires that you enter terminal. Terminal can be intimidating for long-time Windows users because it looks like cmd. It's much easier than cmd though, so don't worry. Just copy and paste the commands into the terminal and it will automatically install everything for you without you needing to click a thing.

Just to be ultra-specific, these are the commands you need to install boot-repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```